# Flexbox child shrinks beyond set minimum width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having a serious CSS challenge on a small project I'm building:

I have a `<main>` element which is set as flexbox of row. inside are 3 children:

```css
:root {
  --clr-light-text: #f2f2f2;
  --clr-dark-text: #48484a;
  --shadow-default: 0px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  --vid-container-h: 0px;
  color: var(--clr-light-text);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--clr-dark-text);
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.glass {
  background-image: linear-gradient( 135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  box-shadow: var(--shadow-default);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.main-container {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 75%);
  padding-bottom: 10rem;
  position: relative;
}

.weather-box {
  width: clamp(13.5rem, 18%, 20rem);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 0 1em 1em 1em;
}

#weather-icon {
  margin: -15% -10%;
}

.weather-details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#forecast,
#temp,
#humidity {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#temp {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-weight: 200;
}

#temp-num {
  font-size: 3em;
}

#humid {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#humid-value {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 200;
}

#humid-value img {
  max-width: 1em;
}

#forecast-desc {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.playlist-box {
  width: clamp(13.5rem, 18%, 20rem);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1rem 0.5em;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.playlist-box h3::after {
  content: '';
  width: 70%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 100vmax;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

#playlist {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#playlist li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

#playlist li:hover,
#playlist li:focus {
  background-image: linear-gradient( 135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  box-shadow: var(--shadow-default);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.song-title {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.vid-thumb {
  width: 100%;
  /* object-position: center;
  object-fit: cover; */
}

.video-container {
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding: 1em;
}

#song-frame {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

#song-frame iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <main>
    <aside class="weather-box glass">
      <div id="forecast">
        <img id="weather-icon" src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/02d@4x.png" alt="Weather Icon" />
        <span id="forecast-desc">(--)</span>
      </div>
      <div class="weather-details">
        <div id="temp">
          <span id="temp-num">0&deg;c</span>
          <span id="feels-like">feels like 0&deg;c</span>
        </div>
        <div id="humidity">
          <span id="humid">Humidity</span>
          <div id="humid-value">
            <span id="humid-num">0%</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </aside>

    <div class="video-container glass">
      <div id="song-frame">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oG08ukJPtR8" title="YouTube video player" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" width="1024" height="576" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <aside class="playlist-box glass">
      <h3>Browse Playlist:</h3>
      <ul id="playlist">
        <li>
          <h4>Song Title</h4>
          <img class="vid-thumb" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ru0K8uYEZWw/hqdefault.jpg" alt="" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <h4>Song Title</h4>
          <img class="vid-thumb" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pkCyfBibIbI/hqdefault.jpg" alt="" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
  </main>
</div>
```

I applied to both `<aside>` elements to have a responsive width with the following `width: clamp(13.5rem, 18%, 20rem)`. The div in the center uses the rest of the available width of the viewport. Generally, the layout kinda works.

The `weather-container`'s clamp works just fine. The `playlist-container` though is able to shrink to less than 13.5rem (216px) and in some screen sizes I'm left with uneven containers in the sides.

The interesting part is that problem is somehow connected to the `<img>` thumbnails. The set width for them is 100%. If I cancel it out, the container behaves correctly but the thumbnails are cut off.

- setting a fixed `width` value doesn't work.
- setting a `min-width` to the element doesn't work.
- setting `flex-shrink: 0;` to the element doesn't work.
- messing with `flex-basis` also didn't work for me.
- changing the `<img>` to a `<div>` with `background-image` instead produces the same result.

Would love to get over this problem, thank you.

**Edit:** I've produced a CodePen which recreates the problem: https://codepen.io/xandertem/pen/XWZLaVR

Try going to responsive mode and see the right section shrinking around <560px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `flex-shrink: 0` to the `aside` (`.playlist-box`) solves the problem.

You should probably add the same rule to the other `aside` (`.weather-box`), even though you don't need it, just in case the type of content in that container ever changes. As you can see, images and videos make a difference.

Comment: Wow. Like I mentioned, I could have sworn I tried that and it didn't work. But for some reason it does now. Maybe it's related to other changes I've made in the code since than. 

In anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons I don't understand clamp in the width setting of flex just does not seem to work.

Also to automatically have the two asides with the height of the middle item you could use grid.

To get round what seems to be the clamp problem this snippet separates out the ranges by using min and max width media queries [when 18% is 13.5rem the overall width is 75rem and so on).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 18% 1fr 18%;
  width: 100vw;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 75rem) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 13.5rem 1fr 13.5rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 111.111rem) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 20rem 1fr 20rem;
  }
}

main {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.weather-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 0 1em 1em 1em;
}

.video-container {
  padding: 1em;
}

.playlist-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1rem 0.5em;
}

.vid-thumb {
  width: 100%;
  /* object-position: center;
  object-fit: cover; */
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="weather-container">
    ...divs...
  </div>
  <div class="video-container">
    <div>
      <iframe>...</iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="playlist-container">
    <h3>Browse Playlist:</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h4>Song Title</h4>
        <img class="vid-thumb" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/example.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>etc...</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift replies 

First I just want to point out that the clamp works perfectly for the first child. I already found out that it has something to do with its content, since canceling out the width of the `img` element inside it makes the problem disappear (but than I have another problem with how the thumbnails are displayed).


Second, It's a bummer to have al these media queries but if it solves it I'll take it. The thing with this grid solution is that I would like the content to stick to each other in the middle when the screen gets larger. Anyway to do that?

Comment: How big do you want the middle item to be when the two asides are at 20rem?

Comment: I want it to be 64rem.